# The specified field <field> could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question: I have 3 tables in Access -

```
Assignments (Date, Parent Company ID, Sales Rep ID)
Roster (Date, Sales Rep ID, Team ID)
Goals (Date, Team ID)
```

First I left joined `Roster` on assignments to get a final `Roster` table and I am trying to left join this new table on `Goals` but I am getting an error that says:

```
Specified field FR.date could refer to more than one table listed in the from clause of your SQL statement.
```

Below is the SQL:

```
SELECT * 
  from Goals as G
         LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT *
               FROM Assignments AS A 
                     LEFT JOIN Roster AS R 
                       ON (A.[Sales Rep ID] = R.[User ID]) 
                        AND (A.Date = R.Date)
            ) FR 
         on (G.Date = FR.Date)
             AND G.[Team ID] = FR.[Team ID]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which daabase technology is it? Did you really need to tage 3 different kinds?

Comment: @Jorge That indentation is awful, worse than the original!

Comment: You can't use `select *`  when joining tables with same field name. You would need to manually mention the column names in the `SELECT` clause. You need to specify either G.Date or FR.Date to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: @DavidG Well, most of sql formatters uses this kind of style. Is a matter of taste. Fell free to edit as what you like. When I started the edit it wasn't even formatted

Comment: @JorgeCampos There's no formatter that would indent like that, which one does that?

Comment: You are selecting all attributes from Assignments and Roster, both have the attribute Date, so the sql engine doesn't know which you are referring too.

Comment: Do Assignments  and Roster have a "date" column?

Comment: @DavidG first result on google... http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm another: https://www.freeformatter.com/sql-formatter.html#ad-output

Comment: @JorgeCampos I recommend the second one on the list then, that way you won't get 7 levels of indentation... http://www.sql-format.com/

Comment: @DavidG I'm glad that I can disagree with you :) (still a free world). Like I said, fell free to edit. cheers

Comment: @isaace Yes they both have a date column

Answer (score 1):

this query

```
SELECT *
           FROM Assignments AS A 
                 LEFT JOIN Roster AS R 
                   ON (A.[Sales Rep ID] = R.[User ID]) 
                    AND (A.Date = R.Date)
```

contains 2 column with the same field name, in this case **Date** and when you write G.Date=FR.Date you have an ambiguous reference to the field **Date** of table A or R

Comment: Is it possible for you to write the revised version of what it should look like?

Comment: Is it possible for you to write the revised version of what it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this, although MS Access does require extra parentheses in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (Goals as G LEFT JOIN
      Assignments AS A 
      ON G.Date = A.Date AND G.[Team ID] = A.[Team ID] 
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Roster as R
     ON A.[Sales Rep ID] = R.[User ID] AND A.Date = R.Date;
```

It is unclear where `[Team ID]` comes from, so you may need to put that condition in the second `ON` clause.

Comment: @JesseNarang Is it just the missing square bracket after `[User ID`?

Comment: @shawnt00 When I click Run it shows a dialog box that says "Enter Parameter Value for A.Date"

Comment: @JesseNarang . . . According to your table descriptions, `A` as a column called `Date`.